# Relationship figure on Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to ask how to write the following two types of figure on Tikz:

[image: figure]

I didn't find a similar question for that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! You only need to find the point where the tangent of an ellipse vanishes. Let's call the rotation angle of the right ellipse `alpha`, and its "radii" `a` and `b`. Then this angle is `atan(b*cot(alpha)/a)`. Here is an example with `R=1;a=2.7;b=1.8;alpha=30;`, where `R` is the radius of the circle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=1;a=2.7;b=1.8;alpha=30;},
    nodes={fill=white,font=\sffamily,align=center}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myt}{atan(b*cot(alpha)/a)}
  \draw (0,R) circle[radius=R*1cm] (0,2*R) node {test 3\\more\\ text};
  \draw[rotate=alpha] (\myt:a*1cm and b*1cm) 
     circle[x radius=a*1cm,y radius=b*1cm]
  (\myt:a*2.5cm and b*1cm)  node{test 2\\ more text};
  \draw[rotate=180-alpha] (-\myt:a*1cm and b*1cm) 
   circle[x radius=a*1cm,y radius=b*1cm]
   (-\myt:a*2.5cm and b*1cm)  node{test 1\\ more text};
 % 
 \begin{scope}[xshift={sqrt(2)*a*2cm+1cm}]
  \draw (0,R) circle[radius=R*1cm] (0,2*R) node {test 3};
  \draw[rotate=alpha] (\myt:a*1cm and b*1cm) 
     circle[x radius=a*1cm,y radius=b*1cm]
  (\myt:a*2.2cm and b*1cm)  node{test 2};
  \draw[rotate=180-alpha] (-\myt:a*1cm and b*1cm) 
   circle[x radius=a*1cm,y radius=b*1cm]
   (-\myt:a*2.2cm and b*1cm)  node{test 1};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The values `2.5` and `2.2` that multiply `a` in the labels need to be adjusted that you are satisfied with the outcome.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I need! One more question, can I start a new line in the name of ellipse i.e., test 1, test 2, and test3? For example, if we use a long name like "test 1 in an ellipse", I want to divide it as two lines "test 1" and "in an ellipse".

Comment: Thank you very much!